# When I export the PDF the custom code is not recognized

Tags: sql, pdf, reporting-services, reportbuilder, custom-code

I have a written some custom code ( a simple function to maintain a sum) in SSRS Report properties (in report builder).

Everything works fine when I render the report in Report Viewer or export the report on an Excel or Word. But the custom code is not recognized when I render the report to PDF.

Can someone help me identify what is going on please?

This is the custom Code:

```
Public Dim gallons_total  As DECIMAL

    Public Function CalculateGallons ( gallons As Double) As Double

        gallons_total= gallons_total+ gallons

    Return gallons

End Function
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not recognised"?

Comment: After testing the custom code in my environment, I find that the custom code will run again when exporting the report, so when we run the report on Report Server and export it to PDF, the custom code will be run twice, the value will be counted twice